# Creating a simple timestamp and testing if it has expired

Tags: php

I am trying to learn how to create and test for the expiration of a timestamp. I set up a simple example, trying to test for a timestamp that has expired, but it does not seem to work correctly, and I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out why it wouldn't echo 'valid' and 'expired' in the appropriate times?

```
<?php

echo'
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>';

//set static current time
$timestamp = 1340037073;

if($timestamp <= strtotime("+10 minutes", $timestamp)){
    echo "Valid";
}else{
    echo "Expired";
}


echo'
</body>
</html>';




?>
```

Comment: why not just use: `if($timestamp <= ($timestamp + (60*10))){`

Comment: $timestamp will always be less than $timestamp + 10 minutes.

Comment: Save `strtotime("+10 minutes", $timestamp)` to a variable and see what the value is

Comment: @Tim why should I? Please explain your example... otherwise it is useless to type a line of code and say why not use.... (x(=9/3^))!!2)759 :) I am sure your answer will be useful, if you elaborate.

Comment: Shouldn't those two be switched inside your condition? Timestamp is always smaller than timestamp + anything

Comment: I agree, though, I tried to switch the condition, it still doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @MHZ timestamp, or time(), is just seconds since the Unix Epoch.  So if you are adding 10 minutes, that is 600 seconds. You are using unnecessary functions by using strtotime for something that simple.

Comment: Doesn't work correctly is neither an error message nor a problem description

Comment: @Tim, thanks for the response. Well, I am starting off simple, my plan is to use it for months, of years, etc... but I guess the exact number of seconds can always be calculated, it is not that hard to just do 60*60*24*182.5 (for 6 months).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

current time is obtained with `time()` function, so `$timestamp` should contain the time obtained from the external source, like database, or whatever, to be checked against current time, to see if it has expired:

```
//test timestamp
$timestamp = 1340037073;

//check if it has expired (600 = 60*10 seconds = 10 minutes)
if ((time() - $timestamp) < 600)
{
  echo 'valid';
}
else
{
  echo 'expired';
}
```

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: thanks for the reply. so my question is, when creating a timestamp, if I know I am checking for the time stamp to expire in lets say 1 month or 6 months, is it always easier to calculate the number of seconds and create conditional statements for comparison like you did above?

Comment: I think there are two ways to check expiration date: 1. see if a given number of seconds has already passed (to check if session is valid, for example), or 2. see if a certain date has come (e.g., for a contest which answers must be given before a given day).

Comment: In this case i did suppose that you wanted to check if a certain time has passed from that `$timestamp`, so i choose the first method. Instead of 600 seconds, you could use `60*10` to to make it clear that you are checking agains 60 seconds * 10 = 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

What you have will always be valid. Consider this:

```
$i = 0;

if ($i <= ($i+1)) {
  // always truthy, because 1 is greater than 0
}
```

So you should switch it:

```
$timestamp = 1340037073;

if(strtotime("+10 minutes", $timestamp) <= $timestamp){
    echo "Valid";
} else {
    echo "Expired";
}
```

Also: why not start using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) while you are at it?

Answer (score 1):

More easy: (600 = 10 minutes in seconds)

```
if (($timestamp+600) <= time()) {
    //expired
}
```